# Ember & Typescript - how to inject router service

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I am trying to inject RouterService into my controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import RouterService from '@ember/routing/router-service';


export default class Search extends Controller.extend({
  // anything which *must* be merged to prototype here
}) {
    @service router!: RouterService;


    @action
    actionClick(){
        this.router.transitionTo('protected.apk.detail')
    }
}

// DO NOT DELETE: this is how TypeScript knows how to look up your controllers.
declare module '@ember/controller' {
  interface Registry {
    'search': Search;
  }
}
```

but I get an error: `Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:router'`
I guess it's because there is not service:router, but router:main instead.
Can you advise me, how to properly inject RouterService?
This controller is in my engine.
ember version: 3.18.0

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type definitions at the bottom of the service are a clue.

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { Registry as Services } from '@ember/service';

export default class Search extends Controller {
    @service router!: Services['router'];

    @action
    actionClick(){
        this.router.transitionTo('protected.apk.detail')
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helped me to understand, how DI works in ember-typescript, but unfortunately I am getting the same error. I do not understand, why is Ember looking for `service:router ` and not `router:main`

Comment: router:main is extended in the router.js file; service:router is the new router service. See https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService for the router service, https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/ for router.js

Comment: ok, so the problem was that I had to add service:router as engine dependency, because I need it after all - thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import type RouterService from '@ember/routing/router-service';

export default class MyService extends Service {
  @service declare router: RouterService;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you inject router service as follow

```
@service router;
```

Comment: The question was about doing that with TypeScript.